# Viewing list from database using Visual Basic in Xojo

Tags: mysql, vba, mysql-workbench, xojo

Every time I run the application I am presented with this error message and would like to know how I can alter my code so it runs
[Error details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDFKQ.png)

Answer (score 2):

`RecordSet` is not meant to be used in that way. `SQLSelect` will return a `RecordSet`, so you don't want to declare a new one with the `new` keyword.

Documentation: http://docs.xojo.com/RecordSet

If you fix that, the other errors should suppress.